# Replace certain word in textbox with vb and retrieve whole string after

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to make an application that replaces a users selected word with underscores, the issue here is the fact that it does that well, however, it does not return the entire string but rather the underscores themselves.

```
tbText.Text = Replace(tbText.Text, tbText.SelectedText,
      generateUnderscores(tbText.SelectedText), tbText.SelectionStart, 1)
```

Generateunderscores is a function i created that returns underscores depending on the number of letters in the selectedtext

tbText is the textbox, when a user highlights it I want this function to run. This will replace the selected text with underscores.

Notice how I make tbText.Text contain this, it then becomes ONLY underscores without the remainder of the text in the textbox.

How can I return the text in the text-box as-well as the underscores in it?
I've tried using a string replace however, the issue with that was it found multiple words instead of the ONE word I wanted removed (selected word)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when a user highlights it I want this function to run` I dont know how you will do this part, because there is no `TextSelected` or `SelectedTextChanged` event.  I used right mouse down.  You could try to use Left Mouse Up, but that means the text is changed even if the user wants to made a mistake or wants to change whats selected.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) 
                  Handles TextBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right AndAlso 
               TextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0 Then

        TextBox1.SelectedText = MakeUnderScores(TextBox1.SelectedText.Length)

    End If
End Sub

Function MakeUnderScores(n As Integer) As String
    Return New String("_"c, n)
End Function
```

I am not sure that VB's `Replace` function wouldn't do the same as `String.Replace`

Comment: I cant believe how simple that was and i still couldnt get my mind around it. The solution to this was the making selectedtext = the underscores. Thanks heaps!